# Peers can connect to VPN server but not between themselves (Packet filtered)

Tags: routing, fedora, iptables, wireguard, firewalld

I'm new into VPN topic and routing in general, and wanted to learn new thinks while setting up wireguard. However I'm facing an issue that I can't resolve for some time.

As in title: Peers can connect to VPN server but not between themselves.
I have connection between vpn server and peers (both ways)

```
[root@<Peer1>]# ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.62 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.62 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.24 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.239/2.160/3.620/1.043 ms

root@<VPN Server>:~# ping 10.0.0.2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.876 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.876/1.062/1.249/0.186 ms
```

But not between peers

```
[root@dev wireguard]# ping 10.0.0.3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered
^C
--- 10.0.0.3 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2003ms
```

One of may hosts, lets call it **Main_host** is running wireguard service with following config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <mainhost_priv>

PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp8s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp8s0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
#DEV
PublicKey = <Peer1_pub>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
Endpoint = <my_pub_IP>:51820
[Peer]
#T14
PublicKey = <Peer2_pub>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
Endpoint = <my_pub_IP>:51820
[Peer]
#phone
PublicKey = <Peer3_pub>=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32
Endpoint = <my_pub_IP>:51820
```

with route

```
root@<main>:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp8s0
0.0.0.0         172.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    20425  0        0 br_int
10.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wg0
10.0.0.3        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wg0
10.0.0.4        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wg0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     425    0        0 br_int
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp8s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp8s0
root@<main>:~#
```

My router is pointing to **Main_host** local IP 192.168.0.100:5128
On the same **Main_host** there is also kvm host **Peer1** with config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2
PrivateKey = <Peer1_priv>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <mai_host_pub>
Endpoint = test.jawor.org:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

**Peer2 and 3** - separate machines - have similar config with changed Address

=== Edit ===
I've found that disabling firewalld helped. But that's rather bad workaround than solution.

In tcpdump for that wg0 I've found:

00:36:11.799053 IP <main_host>> 10.0.0.3: ICMP host 10.0.0.2 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 68